# creating a list of all possible combination from a given list of words in python

Tags: python, string, combinations

i have a problem to create a list of all possible combinations of a given list of words.
the result should be a combination per line for all possible words. the max lengh of combination is based on the amount of words given in the input file. this means, if the file contains 7 words, the combination is max 7 words long. the output should be formated like shown below:

germany
germanygermany
germanygeranygermany
germanyspain
germanygermanyspain
germanygermanyspain

etc etc.

i've googled a bit and figured out, that itertools would be a possible solution for me.

the given words are located in a file called input.txt

i used this code from the Stack overflow entry here:

[How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top)

i just represent the main part as the file read part and file output is not part of the problem here.

so my given list of words is:
germany
spain
albania
netherlands

which works fine

```
from itertools import combinations


features = ['germany', 'spain', 'albania']
tmp = []
for i in range(len(features)):
    oc = combinations(features, i + 1)
    for c in oc:
        tmp.append(list(c))
print (tmp)
```

The output is not as expected.

as my list contains 3 words i changed the code:

germany
spain
albania

which works fine

```
from itertools import combinations


features = ['germany', 'spain', 'albania']
tmp = []
for i in range(len(features)):
    oc = combinations(features, i + 1)
    for c in oc:
        tmp.append(list(c))
print (tmp)
```

but, i believe the result is not as expected, it should be ALL possible combinations.
some combinations are missing, for example:

```
germany
germany germany
germany germany spain 
germany germany germany
```

or something.

(the output is limited to 3 as the given list contains 3 words in the original question).

How do i get the germany germany etc combinations to the output and why are they missing?
i believe i should have the same issues when i use numbers as pins or something.
it cant start at 0 to 9999 but there should be a 00 and 000 and 0000 also in the list.

best regards
Fred

Comment: Those lists have 3 things, not 4. it would help if the scripts match the text.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to use the function [combinations_with_replacement](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement):

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement


features = ['germany', 'spain', 'albania']
tmp = []
for i in range(len(features)):
    oc = combinations_with_replacement(features, i + 1)
    for c in oc:
        tmp.append(list(c))
print (tmp)
```

Comment: Thanks for the possible solution. when using 1,2,3,4 as features, at least the 2,1 is missing. therefore, i still believe its not complete.
[['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4'], ['1', '1'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '4'], ['2', '2'], ['2', '3'], ['2', '4'], ['3', '3'], ['3', '4']

Comment: You said combinations, not permutations. My answer gives all combinations. In this case [2, 1] is the same as [1, 2]. If you want a different answer, you should update your question.